# Code to uncompress compressed data in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, compression

I need some help to find code that will uncompress a string of compressed data. For example if i enter
'4a2b' the program will output 'aaaabb'

```
from itertools import groupby
s = code_to_uncompress=input('Please enter the code?')
#s = '4a2b'
ss = [''.join(list(g)) for k, g in groupby(s, key=lambda x: x.isdigit())]
s_ = []
for i in range(len(ss)):
    if i%2 != 0:
        s_ += int(ss[i-1])*ss[i]
s_ = ''.join(s_)
s_
```

i want to be able to enter any string of compressed data and uncompress it. It should work based on the input of variable code_to_uncompress

Comment: please can someone help edit it

Comment: What should be the output of `decode('12123')`? Or to put it another way: how should I encode both "11111111111133" and "2333333333333" using the same compression format?

Comment: only to compress uncompressed data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use the following code to achive the result you are after:

```
import re
test_str = "4a2b"

def multiply_char(c, num):
    return c *num


def uncompress_str(s):
    digits_str = [s for s in re.findall("\d", s)]
    for dig in digits_str:
        indx = s.find(dig)
        sub_str_replace = multiply_char(s[indx+1], int(dig))
        pat = s[indx:indx+2]
        s = s.replace(pat, sub_str_replace,1)
    return s
```

The output for the `test_str = "4a2b"` is:

```
print(uncompress_str(test_str))
aaaabb
```

The output for a user input string is:

```
test_str = input("Enter String: ")
print(uncompress_str(test_str))
Enter String: 5d4c7i8q
dddddcccciiiiiiiqqqqqqqq
```

I prefer to always separate to functions, but you can do it without the function and as part of loops

**Added check of input from user on windows and ubuntu**

*Ubuntu*:

```
davidsr@complex1:/data2/davidsr$ python3 test.py 
Enter String: 4a3b5g6y
aaaabbbgggggyyyyyy
```

*Windows*:

```
C:\Users\davidsr\PycharmProjects\test_matan>py test.py
Enter String: 4a3b
aaaabbb
```

Comment: Is that what you needed?

Comment: 4a2b is an example this peice of code does not work for me. please can you change it if you can

Comment: @BenNoimark what does it mean that it doesn't work for you? what examples did you tried? where the problem occur on your machine?

Comment: i need something that works based on what the user inputs not just for a test string

Comment: @BenNoimark This works for any string of the type you specified, meaning that if a user will enter a string and you will call the function it will output the desired result; I dont understand where did you asked to read data from user

Comment: the whole point is the user can type the string into the shell and the code uncompresses what is input by the user. test_str does not help as the user of the program does not have access to the code.

Comment: when i entered it into python it did not come up with any results

Comment: @Ben915 what kind of shell, what type of operating system; I checked and it worked on both windows CMD and ubuntu terminal (for python 3)

Comment: idle python 3.7 64-bit does that mean anything to you?

Comment: where do you use test_str = input("Enter String: ")
print(uncompress_str(test_str)) in the program it onlly works if i use that piece of code but after i input my example it comes up with an error

Comment: @Ben915 see the link: https://repl.it/repls/VagueFrailDeskscan It doesnt recognize the function because you call it before the decleration

Answer (score 1):

Look forward a better solution,here is my code:

```
from itertools import groupby
s = '4a2b'
ss = [''.join(list(g)) for k, g in groupby(s, key=lambda x: x.isdigit())]
s_ = []
for i in range(len(ss)):
    if i%2 != 0:
        s_ += int(ss[i-1])*ss[i]
s_ = ''.join(s_)
s_
```

Output:

```
'aaaabb'
```

Comment: when itried it it didn't output anything to enter the code